# Logging Diagnostics info to RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm currently using Nlog to store diagnostic type messages. I'm considering logging these message to a message queue (RabbitMQ with Masstransit) and these can then be consumed to a database for analysis.

Current speeds to publish / log a message on my PC are:-

- Nlog : 40ms
- Sql Server via petapoco : 110ms
- RabbitMq via masstransit    (Publish): 490ms

I though publishing to message queue would be a lot quicker. Are there settings in Masstrainsit / RabbitMq that I could tweak to speed it up?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the first message I sent was high (400ms+)... but...

All subsequent messages had an average speed of 12ms. The first message was probably initialising the message bus. but once setup it's very fast :-)

Comment: Add Nlog and Sql server also increased their speeds too, after the first send

Comment: And if your logs aren't mandatory, just don't await the send, and turn off publisher acknowledgements and it will publish even quicker to RMQ.